# How do I list columns not inherited from base classes?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have this class:

```
class DataCommonInfoText(models.Model):
    a_col = model.TextField()
    def is_data(self):
        return True

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And a class that inherits from it:

```
class MoreData(DataCommonInfoText):
    another_col = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to list as strings all the columns in `MoreData` that are not inherited from `DataCommonInfoText`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inherit from an abstract class the field is considered to be local ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)).
So in order to obtain only the fields actually declared in the current class you will have to compute all fields from current class and from the base class and then perform a set subtraction between then.

To obtain all fields of a certain model use: `Model._meta.get_fields()`

Ex:

```
allFields = set([f.name for f in MoreData._meta.get_fields()])
baseFields = set([f.name for f in DataCommonInfoText._meta.get_fields()])
derivedOnlyFields = allFields - baseFields
```

This should solve the problem.

As a final step if you want to put the items on a string you can just use `join` with whatever separator you want:

```
fieldStr = ", ".join(derivedOnlyFields)
```